# ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 64) are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm currently trying to build a classification model in keras but I keep getting a shape error. This is my model right now. Is there anything that I am doing wrong?

```
predictors=["Length", "Diameter", "Height", "Shucked weight", "Viscera weight", "Shell weight", "Rings"]
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test =train_test_split(db[predictors], db["Sex"], test_size=.2)
x_train= x_train.to_numpy()
x_test = x_test.to_numpy()
y_train = y_train.to_numpy()
y_test = y_test.to_numpy()

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(7,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy'], 
    )

x_val = x_train[:1000]
partial_x_train = x_train[1000:]
y_val = y_train[:1000]
partial_y_train = y_train[1000:]
partial_x_train.shape

history = model.fit(partial_x_train,
                    partial_y_train,
                    epochs=20,
                    batch_size=512,
                    validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

```
 ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 64) are incompatible
```

Data Source https://www.kaggle.com/rodolfomendes/abalone-dataset

Comment: Would you please add more details about the task? How is the dataset represented would be good to know so that we can help you better understand your code.

Comment: @subspring I've added a link to the data source I am using, I am trying to classify the sex as M, F or I

Answer (score 0):

The output of the last layer consists of 64 different values, while your labels are of 1 value only.

Comment: Is there any way to change this?

Comment: in the last dense layer, instead of 64 put 3, and change labels from one value to 3 values (one-hot encoding)

Comment: You might find this link helpful: https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-prepare-categorical-data-for-deep-learning-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

This error is because you have 3 classes(labels) in your dataset and you are not defining those in your model's last layer. (As mentioned by @subspring)

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(7,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(3))  # You need to mention this in the last dense layer
```

As the label data in this dataset is not numeric.

```
y_train.unique() #array(['I', 'M', 'F'], dtype=object)
```

For that, you can use **LabelEncoder** as below:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

def Labels(y_train, y_test):
    LabEnc = LabelEncoder()
    LabEnc.fit(y_train)
    Enc_y_train = LabEnc.transform(y_train)
    Enc_y_test = LabEnc.transform(y_test)
    return Enc_y_train, Enc_y_test

y_train, y_test = Labels(y_train, y_test)

y_train  # array([1, 1, 2, ..., 2, 2, 0])
```

Now train the model by converting the input data `(x_train,x_test)` into an array.

```
x_train= np.array(x_train)
x_test = np.array(x_test) 

#compile the model 
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

x_val = x_train[:1000]
partial_x_train = x_train[1000:]
y_val = y_train[:1000]
partial_y_train = y_train[1000:]
partial_x_train.shape

#train the model
history = model.fit(partial_x_train,
                    partial_y_train,
                    epochs=5,
                    batch_size=512,
                    validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/5
5/5 [==============================] - 2s 80ms/step - loss: 0.8610 - accuracy: 0.3302 - val_loss: 0.7966 - val_accuracy: 0.2350
Epoch 2/5
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 13ms/step - loss: 0.7997 - accuracy: 0.2563 - val_loss: 0.7491 - val_accuracy: 0.4620
Epoch 3/5
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 16ms/step - loss: 0.7917 - accuracy: 0.3315 - val_loss: 0.7883 - val_accuracy: 0.2680
Epoch 4/5
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step - loss: 0.7949 - accuracy: 0.3405 - val_loss: 0.7499 - val_accuracy: 0.3390
Epoch 5/5
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 13ms/step - loss: 0.7884 - accuracy: 0.3306 - val_loss: 0.7605 - val_accuracy: 0.3670
```